# Absolute Continuity for 0 Radon Nikodym derivative set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, absolute-convergence

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be positive $\sigma$-finite measures on $(S,\Sigma)$ with $\nu \ll \mu$ and let $h = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$.

I want to show that
\begin{align}
\mu\big(\{h=0\}\big)=0 \iff \mu \ll \nu.
\end{align}
Therefore, in the "$\impliedby$" direction, I assume that $\mu\big(\{h=0\}\big)>0$ but I face some difficulties with finding an exhausting sequence $(A_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset S$ for both $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Beside this, in the "$\implies$" direction, how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\mu(h = 0) = 0$. Let $A$ be such that $\nu(A) = 0$. Then $\int_A h\ d\mu = 0$. Then $\int_{A\cap\{h > 0\}} h\ d\mu = 0$. Then $\mu(A\cap\{h>0\}) = 0$. Then $\mu(A) = 0$. Then $\mu \ll \nu$.

Conversely, suppose that $\mu \ll \nu$. Then, since $\nu(\{h = 0\}) = \int_{\{h = 0\}} h\ d\mu = 0$, $\mu(\{h = 0\}) = 0$.

Comment: Okido, the above steps are very understandable indeed. Analogously, if I want to show that $\nu \ll \mu \implies \nu(\{h=0\})=0$, can I take for granted that $\mu(\{h=0\})=\int_{\{h=0\}} h\ d\nu =0$ to conclude that $\nu(\{h=0\})=0$?

Comment: @iJup: I assume you meant to say that you want to show that $\nu \ll \mu \implies \nu(h=0) = 0$. Then $\nu(h = 0) = \int_{\{h=0\}} h\ d\mu = 0$.

Comment: @iJup: By the way, if you are satisfied with my answer, I'd appreciate it if you click the check mark next to it, to indicate that you accept it. Thanks. :)